# Android - What is happens after calling startScan method of WifiManager

Tags: android, wifimanager, access-point, network-scan

I'm trying to do something like this tutorial [Android Wi-Fi Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm) to scan for the available access points. I have a line of code in the receiver to output a message "**Calling receiver**" each time that receiver is called when the scanning process completed. I have called `startScan` method only one, but I can see that the receiver is called a more times, and the frequency is abitrary. The log messages is like this:

```
04-28 15:49:39.190   calling receiver

04-28 15:50:50.945   calling receiver

04-28 15:50:56.480  calling receiver

04-28 15:55:41.480  calling receiver

04-28 16:00:26.840  calling receiver

04-28 16:05:12.000  calling receiver

04-28 16:09:57.115 calling receiver
```

So the log messages tell me that the receiver is called with the abitrary frequency. Can anyone tell me what is happens each time I call startScan method? Is it start a new thread that will do the scan and will repeat that scan? If so, how I can stop that thread and how I can change the frequency of that thread?

Comment: You could look through the Android source code, but I don't think it would help you. This is not something the API documents and so it's not something you need to know. It could also be different between different version of Android, so it's better not to try to write your code based on this.

Comment: So how I can scan for available access points if I dont rely on this? I need to be able to continuous scan for access points at a regular interval.

Comment: You don't have any control over that code. Even if you knew what it did, how would that help you? The only thing you can do is implement your own timing management, or change your product requirements based on what you are experiencing with the device.

Answer (score 0):

This receiver ll always be called whenever a new wifi ll be found by reciever,that's why your logcat printing the calling reciever method.

Comment: I can see sometime there is no different of the access ponits between previous call and current call. Is it also called each time there is some changes like signal strength?

Comment: please go through this tutorial              http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm                And let me know for more help.